# What type of weeds are these?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

I've tried looking but I can't seem to find the name of these weeds (in Australia):

[image]

The leaves don't grow any larger than in the photo. It is vine-type and can spread for metres. Vine-root stuff is is just below the surface. Gets a small red flower.

[image]

The weeds always grow in a clump. They don't get any larger than they are but spread like the plague and kill any grass it covers.

Anyone have any idea what they are?

Comment: Those look like two different plants -- the leaves on the bottom photo look smooth, while those on the top photo are toothed?

Comment: There are two different weeds...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mis-parsed the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top image is of [Carolina Mallow (*Modiola caroliniana*)](http://www.iewf.org/weedid/modiola_caroliniana.htm) and the bottom picture is of [Cudweed (*Gamochaeta americana*)](http://plantnet.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/cgi-bin/NSWfl.pl?page=nswfl&lvl=sp&name=Gamochaeta~americana).

Comment: can you improve your answer by adding more detail like the Latin name or other details about the plants and how  you identified these plants?

Comment: I identified them looking at Australian government sites for know weeds. Theses are just the common names as that is what most people are familiar with.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>The top photo looks like [Creeping Charlie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glechoma_hederacea) (Glechoma hederacea). Look at [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/224/what-are-some-natural-ways-of-killing-ground-ivy-creeping-charlie) for some ideas on dealing with it.</strike>

See @J. Musser's comment below for why my identification is incorrect.

Comment: I disagree with your identification here.

Comment: @J.Musser: please educate me, what's the basis for your disagreement?

Comment: @bstpierre; J. Musser is correct, the top is not Creeping Charlie, it is Carolina Mallow and the bottom is cud-weed. Although very similar to Creeping Charlie, you can see it is Carolina Mallow: http://www.eattheweeds.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/cbm11.jpg

Comment: Hey @bstpierre, sorry for the delay. There quite a few things anatomically wrong with the plant for it to be creeping charlie. It does look similar, but the leaf spacing and rosette formation is wrong, the root is wrong, and those appear to be some type of mallow leaves (not sure which), looking at the venation and margin, as well as the attachment to the petiole.

Comment: @AlexGuerin: you ought to change the accepted answer to yours (I'm only going to leave my answer here so that J.Musser's comment remains)

Comment: @bstpierre You can't delete an accepted answer, but if you want, you can flag for moderator deletion.